# Both structs referring each other

Tags: swift

Given the following situation:

```
struct Book {
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let authors: [Author]
}

struct Author {
    let name: String
    let books: [Book]
}
```

Now we have a strange scenario:

```
var books = [Books]()
var authors = [Authors]()

let author1 = Author(name: "some author", books: [book1]) // ????
let book1 = Book(title: "Some title", authors: [author1]) // ????

books.append(book1)
authors.append(author1)
```

How can we resolve this?

Comment: Don't define it that way. :-) Seriously, if you think of structs like relational DB tables, you should have your answer (hint: it involves using an ID or GUID value in your structs).

Comment: I see. makes sense!